# Does anyone know why I am not getting any results with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I will just go straight to the problem.

This query is supposed to a list of records where PFlag is set to 'No'

However, when I run it, I get blank results.

If I remove the WHERE clause (where pFlag='No'), I get results.

So, the WHERE clause is presenting a problem.

Any idea what is wrong?

Here is the code I am currently running.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.username,
       lg.Email,
       lg.fullname, 
       c.CourseName, 
       l.location, 
       d.trainingDates, 
       d.trainingTime, 
       t.processedFlag,
       i.instructorName 
FROM tblTrainings t 
       INNER JOIN tblCourses c on t.courseId = c.courseId
       INNER JOIN tblLocations l on t.locationId = l.LocationId
       INNER JOIN tblTrainingDates d on t.dateid=d.dateid
       INNER JOIN tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId
       INNER JOIN tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId
       INNER JOIN tblLogin lg on t.username = lg.username
       WHERE t.PFlag = 'No'
 ORDER BY lg.fullname DESC
```

It seems simple enough.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
PFlag
0x59006500
0x59006500
0x59006500
```

Comment: When running it without the where clause - do you have results which has `pFlag='No'` ?

Comment: If you're definitely seeing some "No" records in your results, my only guess is that there's some extra whitespace in those values, like `[space]No` or `No[space][space]` or something like that, which would cause the filter to fail.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, excellent question. I see where pFlag='Yes'

What is funny though is that I am testing using my username and I can see some pFlag with values of 'No' for my user. So, why isn't the query picking that up?

Comment: Run the query **without** the `where` clause and add this column : `SELECT ...., CAST(t.PFlag  AS VARBINARY(4))` and see the distinct values. maybe you have whitespace (invisible) chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try rewriting the WHERE statement like this:

```
WHERE t.PFlag like '%No%'
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table columns definitions.
if the type of field `pFlag` is `CHAR` with particular length, e.g. `CHAR[4]`, then any string in that column will be filled up to 4 chars.

In that case the real data stored in your table will be `No[space][space]`.

If this is the case, convert your column type to `VARCHAR`, and do an update to that column with `trim()`.

Comment: trailing spaces don't affect equality comparisons. `SELECT CASE WHEN 'No' = CAST('No' AS CHAR(4)) THEN 'Yes' END`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, et al, I am not trying to return fFlag as part of the result. I am only doing so now just to see what it returns.

I tried using the LIKE '%No%'. Still no results returned.

Reason this has to work is that users can sign up for any many classes as possible. Each time the user signs up, the flag changes from No to Yes. If user signs up for another class, then the flag should initially be 'No'. If I change courses under my username to No, it works but doesn't when some are 'Yes' and some are 'No'.

Any idea how to work aroung this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like @user2065377 said :

```
WHERE t.PFlag like '%No%'
```

Also :

Run the query **without** the `where` clause and add this column : `SELECT ...., CAST(t.PFlag  AS VARBINARY(4))` and see the distinct values.

maybe you have whitespace (invisible) chars

also paste the result for :

`select distinct ( t.PFlag) from .....`

## edit

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 0x59006500)` yields `Y`

Where is the `Yes` word ?

even so , it's not an ordinary Y :

`SELECT CASE WHEN  CONVERT(nVARCHAR(100), 0x59006500)='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` ( yields 0)

Comment: If I run select distinct (t.pFlag) from mytable, I get these: `No`
 `Yes`

Comment: @ChidiOkeh what about the varbinary casting ? can u paste the results ?

Comment: I have posted the varbinary casting above.

Please have a look.

Thank you

Comment: I am trying to following your point but I am lost.

When I run my code, I get Yes, not Y. So, I am confused as to your point here sir.